# SQL select duplicated row in a table

Tags: sql

I am trying to select all duplicates from db table:

This is my try:

```
dev=> select * from import_mapper where source_id=12772;
  id   |     entity      | source_id | local_id | venue_id 
-------+-----------------+-----------+----------+----------
 41002 | appointment_mbo |     12772 |    67101 |       50
 46046 | appointment_mbo |     12772 |    67101 |       50
 46192 | appointment_mbo |     12772 |    87814 |      149
 48557 | appointment_mbo |     12772 |    90100 |       66
 49310 | appointment_mbo |     12772 |    90750 |       65
(5 rows)
```

my expected result should be only first 2 row:

```
  id   |     entity      | source_id | local_id | venue_id 
-------+-----------------+-----------+----------+----------
 41002 | appointment_mbo |     12772 |    67101 |       50
 46046 | appointment_mbo |     12772 |    67101 |       50
```

Note: for sure regardless of ID field

Comment: But the `id` values are different in the expected result, then how it can be duplicate?

Comment: for sure regardless of ID field

Comment: did you mean duplicate combination of source_id,local_id ?

Comment: @cableload for all [entity, source_id, local_id, venue_id ]

Comment: BTW, you're likely to get better answers when you are only using relevant tags. Randomly adding tags (because they are about a database) does not help.

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add the tag for the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `WHERE EXISTS` clause over each of the fields you are considering in your uniqueness check:

```
Select  *
From    import_mapper   m1
Where Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    import_mapper   m2
    Where   m1.id != m2.id
    And     m1.entity = m2.entity
    And     m1.source_id = m2.source_id
    And     m1.local_id = m2.local_id
    And     m1.venue_id = m2.venue_id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT im1.*
FROM import_mapper im1
INNER JOIN import_mapper im2
USING (source_id, local_id, venue_id, entity)
WHERE im1.id != im2.id
```

That should give you all duplicates (leaving the `id` out of the equation).

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "source_id"
LINE 4: USING source_id, local_id, venue_id, entity;

i am using PSQL

Comment: I added brackets, guess they were missing. Unless you're not using MySQL, but since you did tag your question as such a MySQL answer should be valid.

Comment: sadly wrong answer, @Siyual already answered it, check his comment

Comment: As usual there are different correct answers. And some answers are correct for one RDBMS and incorrect for another.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a group by on all of the columns except id, and then use having to filter out those with count equal to one. This solution also gets the number of duplicates.

```
select id, entity, source_id, local_id, venue_id, count(*) n from
   import_mapper group by entity, source_id, local_id, venue_id having n > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Most databases support the ANSI standard window functions.  So, you can try:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by entity, source_id, local_id, venue_id) as cnt 
      from t
     ) t
where cnt >= 2;
```

Note that this version will even work intuitively if some of the columns have `NULL` values.